# why i cant printout the output of decorators?

Tags: python, decorator

this is a little simple exercise on decorators but i dont understand why i cannot printout the function output in this case where this two line of code are respectively written in the end  x=f1 - x(f3) but it do when it written like that x=f1(f3)- x()

```
def f1(f):
    def f2():
        print (f'this is before the function call')
        f()
        print (f'this is after the function call')
    return f2

def f3():
    print('this is f3')


x=f1  |the other scenario|  x=f1(f3)
x(f3) |the other scenario|  x()
```

Answer (score 0):

`f1` is a function that returns a function `f2` and is passed a function `f` that is called in the function `f2`. When you assign `x=f1(f3)` you call the function `f1` which returns a function `f2` which is assigned to the variable `x`. When you then call `x()`, x is assigned the function `f2` which is called and in turn calls `f3` which was passed as the variable `f` to `f1`.

if you call `x=f1` you assign the function `f1` to the variable `x`. If you then call `x(f3)` you call the function `f1` and pass `f3` as the argument `f`. `f1` returns a function `f2` which is never called. If you would assign the return value to a new variable y `y=x(f3)` and then call `y()`, the variable `y` is now assigned the function `f2` which when called correctly prints the output.